# Formatting text in vim + jump cursor to after a word's punctuation

Tags: vim

I found myself wondering if there was a way to jump to the position after a word's punctuation. I was formatting the following text:

```
$scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicPopup
```

into:

```
$scope,
$rootScope,
$state,
$ionicPopup
```

I used the following commands:

```
Eli<enter><escape>
Eli<enter><escape>
Eli<enter><escape>
Eli<enter><escape>
```

This seems terribly inefficient.. there must be a better way!

If I could jump to the point after a word's punctuation (call it command `X`), I could use:

```
Xi<enter><escape>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a movement?  Something like this works regardless of the number of columns: `:%s/,\zs /\r/g`.  Or you could use a macro.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I hadn't thought of using regex, is that what you would recommend in a situation such as this? Maybe I need to really bone up my regex skills.

Comment: I'm not sure what "situation like this" means.  But generally, yes, a single replace is typically better than repeating a sequence four times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a substitution:

```
:s/ /\r/g
```

But you could do something like:

```
f r<CR>;.;.
```

See `:help f`, `:help r`, `:help ;` and `:help .`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I need to bone up on my regex.. how have you gone about learning it? any recommended resources?

Comment: Also, I hadn't though of treating whitespace chars as actual characters and "finding" them with `f`..

Comment: I would recommend this regex which is much more accurate `:s/ \(\$\)\@=/\r/g` because there is a case where you don't know how many whitespaces between the words.

Comment: You can repeat the previous action by pressing a dot.

Comment: @JoelBrewer, using Vim.